# C++ What operators I need to overload to make this A1 += A2 * floatValue work?

Tags: c++

What operators I need to overload to make this word?

Variables A1 and A2 both of type class A, variable floatValue is of type float.

```
A1 += A2 * floatValue;
```

I have overloaded this operators

```
A operator+() const;
A operator+=(const A value);
A operator*(const A value);
friend A operator*(const A val2, float val);
```

But, I receive error "Class A has no suitable copy constructor"

I have this constructors in my class

```
A();
A(float val1, float val2);
A(float value);
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: Well as it says you need a copy constructor, like this: A(const A&);

Comment: There is more to `A` than what you posted.  Please post the class interface for `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you overload an assignment operator like

```
A operator+=(const A value);
```

you also need to define a copy constructor like

```
A( const A& );
```

The copy constructor will be used by the assignment operator.

This is part of what's known as the Rule of Three.

Comment: There is already a default copy constructor.  Whether it is suitable and needs to be overridden by a user-defined version is another story, but every class has a copy constructor, **unless** it was turned off.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Right, actually we don't have enought information about `class A`.

Answer (score 3):

Minimal example:

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    float val;

    foo(float val): val(val){}

    foo &operator+=(foo const &other) {
        this->val += other.val;
        return *this;
    }

    friend foo operator*(foo const &lhs, foo const &rhs) {
        return lhs.val*rhs.val;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a = 5, b = 6;
    a += b * 3;
    cout << a.val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/6pD2pr

With an explicit constructor you might want to use this example instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct foo {
    float val;
    explicit foo(float val): val(val){}

    foo &operator+=(foo const &other) {
        this->val += other.val;
        return *this;
    }

    friend foo operator*(foo const &lhs, float val) {
        return foo(lhs.val*val);
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a(5), b(6);
    a += b * 3;

    cout << a.val << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

see: http://ideone.com/o8Vu1d

Comment: `foo(float)` should prob. be `explicit`

Comment: @Thomas why? That would disallow `b * 3`.

Comment: exacty. The OP's `A` might be more than just a float.

Answer (score 0):

When you have function like this:

```
fun(A a);
```

Arguments here are passed by value, so you need to have copy constructor for `A` (in order to create new instance from another instance), OR you can change it to reference, so no copy constructor will be needed. 
Like this:

```
A operator+=(const A &value);
```